# How can i convert my arrays into object or json webscraping

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, web-scraping

### What is the best way to convert *scraped* data array :

`[ 'random product 1',    'random product 2',   'random product 3', 'random product 4']  [ '$99',    '$99',   '$99', '$99']`

---

```
                                              into object
```

---

`{ name: 'random product 1', price: '$100', }{ name: 'random product 2', price: '$100', }{ name: 'random product 3', price: '$100', }`

---

I've tried

```js
var keys = [
        'name',
        'price'
    ]
const mainData = {} 
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        let keyIdx = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            if (l < 2) {
            //bundle.name and bundle.price contains above mentioned array of name and price
                mainData[keys[j]] = bundle.name[l];
                // keyIdx++;
                j++;
                mainData[keys[j]] = bundle.price[l];
            }
```

---

but it returns only one object `{ name: 'random product 3', price: '$99' }`

---

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+from+two+arrays+create+objects+with+properties+at+same+index) of [Combine the values of two arrays into object](/q/42448966/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 arrays with the same length you can map through one of the arrays, and use `i` to link the `name` with the corresponding `price`.

```js
 const names = ['random product 1', 'random product 2', 'random product 3', 'random product 4']
 const prices = ['$99', '$99', '$99', '$99']


 const result = names.map((name, i) => {
   return {
     name,
     price: prices[i]
   }
 });

 console.log(result);
```